# PostgreSQL> column integer[] value check from another table(id)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I want to build an application which use postgresql.
It should be a simple question but I still cannot find the answer quickly enough ; maybe would you help me to do this?

I have a table of ingredients.
id PK, name VARCHAR

I want to create a table of recipies where I got an id and integer[]
But I don't find how to do this: every element of integer[] should be referenced in ingredients.

I can do it with a simple integer REFERENCE ingredients(id) but not with an array.

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a cross-reference table or an XREF table.

How it would work:

> **TABLE 1: ingredients**
>
> id
>
> name

> **TABLE 2: recipes**
>
> id
>
> name
>
> description

> **TABLE 3: recipes_ingredients_xref**
>
> recipes_ingredients_xref_id
>
> recipe_id
>
> ingredient_id

In table 3 (recipes_ingredients_xref), you link multiple ingredients with a single recipe.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I did it with 2 tables items(id PK, name) and recipes(id_craft ref to items, id_ingredient ref to items, qty).